# how can i read a file with extension .123 and how to convert it to Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

How can I read a file with extension `.123` and how to convert it to Microsoft Excel or read it in MATLAB?

I've tried Lotus-1-2-3 but it doesn't work, and this site http://www.tech-faq.com/convert-lotus-123-to-excel.html.

Comment: If Lotus 1-2-3 doesn't work, then maybe it is not a Lotus-1-2-3 file.

Comment: Perhaps check out http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx to see if it can figure out what kind of file you have.